# watch a subdirectory with incron

Tags: linux, bash, incron

I use incron for watch a direcory and run a script if a file is added.
In /etc/incron.d/ I have a file with:

```
/home/pat0/downloads IN_CLOSE_WRITE /var/www/owncloud/scanOC.sh pat0
```

It's ok when I add a file in /home/pat0/downloads
but, if I create a subdirectory and I add in a file no thing run.

For exemple /home/pat0/downloads/test/myfile.txt is not seen.

How can I watch /home/pat0/download and all its future subdirectories and files?

Comment: this should work `/home/pat0/downloads IN_CLOSE_WRITE,recursive=true  /var/www/owncloud/scanOC.sh pat0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think this is possible with incron. Please check with [Watcher](https://github.com/gregghz/Watcher).

Watcher is a daemon that watches specified files/folders for changes and fires commands in response to those changes. It is similar to incron, however, configuration uses a simpler to read yaml file instead of a plain text file. It's also written in Python, making it easier to hack.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/incron/incrontab.5.en.html):

```
... Also, there is the symbol recursive=false. This symbol limits the observation on the specified directory and does not include subdirectories.
```

This rather implies that in the absence of such a flag incrond *will* check sub-directories. However my experience is that it does not. Sadly, specifying recursive=true also does not work.

Comment: specifying `recursive=true` works for me. you need to restart `incrond.service` or reload via `incrontab -d`

Answer (score 0):

Recursive directory watching in incron is a new feature added in version 0.5.12 (see https://github.com/ar-/incron/blob/master/CHANGELOG):

> 0.5.12   2015-02-01
>
> - added recursive directory watching
> - added configuration parameters: recursive, dotdirs and loopable
> - added upstart script
> - extended manpages and readme

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted. 
1. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259
2. https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers